# code sample for filled \heartsuit using txfonts

Tags: symbols, txfonts

try to use `txfonts` to show the play card suit with colors http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/fonts/txfonts/doc/txfontsdocA4.pdf, anyone can provide detail latex file?

like how to use `\vardiamondsuit & \varheartsuit`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\spadesuit$~~K 8 7 3\\
$\textcolor{red}{\varheartsuit}$~~A Q\\
$\textcolor{red}{\vardiamondsuit}$~~8 7 4\\
$\clubsuit$~~J 10 3 2
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use macros to make it easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts,xcolor}
\newcommand\redheartsuit{\textcolor{red}{\varheartsuit}}
\newcommand\reddiamondsuit{\textcolor{red}{\vardiamondsuit}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\spadesuit$~~K 8 7 3\\
$\redheartsuit$~~A Q\\
$\reddiamondsuit$~~8 7 4\\
$\clubsuit$~~J 10 3 2
\end{document}
```

Comment: excellent, so fast to get correct working code sample

Comment: @larrycai Glad to assist!  I edited the answer slightly for consistency.